# PivotViewer - Dynamic images displayed but no text

Tags: image, pivotviewer

Using the PivotViewer's source code, I created a cxml file at http://fhfl15gisweb.flhd.fhwa.dot.gov/DEWA_Accidents/dewa_accidents.cxml.  However, when I run the SL project, images display on the screen, but they empty boxes with neither color-background nor any text (see http://fhfl15gisweb.flhd.fhwa.dot.gov/DEWA_Accidents/#/ProjectSearch).  What is wrong w/ it?  Please share your experience.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your .cxml and .dzi (deep zoom collection file) looks fine.  However, I'm getting 404 errors on your images.  Here is an example of where DZ is looking for your images :

/DEWA_Accidents/DEWA_Accidents-75f090bae7074a6b844c87c0a24906a1_files/4/1_1.jpg

You can use Fiddler 2 to watch your http traffic and help trouble shoot this.

But it looks like either your images directory is in the wrong location or isn't there.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for your feedback.  I am going to install Fiddler2 after I get permission.  Could you advise how to access /DEWA_Accidents/DEWA_Accidents-75f090bae7074a6b844c87c0a24906a1_files/4/1_1.jpg?  Thanks again

Comment: Using installed Fiddler2, I can view the 404 Errors.

Comment: I have continued my debugging on this problem. I have 2 projects, one can successfully create dynamic images (http://fhfl15gisweb.flhd.fhwa.dot.gov/ArraProjects/defaultHost.aspx#/ProjectSearch, termed A here), but another one reported here (http://fhfl15gisweb.flhd.fhwa.dot.gov/DEWA_Accidents/defaultHost.aspx#/ProjectSearch, termed B here) can't. Both A and B's code are essentially the same. Through Fiddler2's Inspector: Raw, the message got are below:

Comment: The B contains some extra content like that: Accept: */* Referer: http://fhfl15gisweb.flhd.fhwa.dot.gov/DEWA_Accidents/ClientBin/DEWA_Accidents.xap Accept-Language: en-us Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate - Does these hint me the reason for the failure of image generation?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the server code on the image request to see if you can track the image issue? Or are the images actually generated and stored on the server?  If so, have you verified that they exist?

Comment: I found that one of the reasons was the missing of the \javascript\Silverlight.js.  After I added this file, I could create dzi file (through Fiddler2), but generation of the .jpg files is still not successful.